# write an IDE for vala

Tags: vala, ide

I wnated to know Why elementary os does not have a decent IDE for vala language?
vala is their programming language but unfortunately there is not a good IDE for it
I think they should have a IDE for vala

Comment: Next time do the research first. https://askubuntu.com/questions/3306/which-ide-should-i-use-for-vala

Comment: https://atom.io/packages/ide-vala

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/6gg89w/ide_for_vala_helping_to_fix_some_bugs_beginner_in/

Comment: Install intellij idea and then this plugin: https://github.com/gregorej/vala-intellij-plugin